# Why do we take value from the already constructed array in KMP algorithmn when moving back when there is a mismatch , instead of starting from first?

Tags: string, algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

Why do we take value from the already constructed array in KMP algorithm when moving back (when there is a mismatch), instead of starting from first?  Also how does it guarantee from that point before, the values are fine?

eg :

```
id = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
s =  a a b a a b a a a
arr  0 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 2
```

Considering `i = 0` and `j = 1`, we start the algorithm.

Why do we have a condition of moving:

```
i > 0 and charAt(i) != charAt(j) then i = arr[i-1]
```

How exactly does this line in KMP work?

Answer (score 2):

`arr` was built specifically to take advantage of what you have already previously matched to get a head start once a mismatch occurs.

For example: suppose you have matched `aabaa`, but the next character isn't the expected `b`, but an `a`.  This means what we have processed so far *ends* with `aa`, which is why `arr[i-1]` is 2: the position where we've matched the `aa` at the start of string we're looking for.